# Delete/ignore unwanted elements in json

Tags: json, linux, bash, hive, apache-pig

I want to delete/ignore the elements in the following json record:

**{"_scroll_id":"==","timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":6908915,"max_score":null,"hits":[**{"_index":"abc_v1","_type":"composite_request_response_v1","_id":"123","_score":1.0,"_source":{"response":{"testResults":{"docsisResults":{"devices":[{"upstreamSection":{"upstreams":[]},"fluxSection":{"fluxInfo":[{}]}}],"events":[]},"mocaResults":{"statuses":[]}}}},"sort":[null,1.0]}**]}}**,

I have the records in the above format. I wish to delete the highlighted part of the  record. Can someone guide me of ways I can accomplish that. Are there anyways I can achieve that using hive/pig/linux/python?

Answer (score 0):

There is the JSON SerDe in Hive, see this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Json+SerDe
 So you can define only columns that you need in table definition, put your file in the table location and then select only defined columns. Alternatively you can pre-process/transform your files before loading them using Java+ Jackson (library to serialize or map Java objects to JSON and vice versa), this will give you maximum flexibility thought this is not so simple as using JSON SerDe.